# Why a Collection of disjoint open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ has only countably many nonempty sets?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I am confused by this question. Why can't we just have a disjoint union of open sets of which every set is non empty?

Comment: We can. But then you will have only countably many sets in this collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $R>0$. Show that a collection of disjoint open sets in $[-R,R]^n$ has only countably many nonempty sets.

Comment: Am sorry for my unrefined and silly logic. Am a social science major trying to self taught some proper mathematical logic to myself.

Can the intuition to the hint be :- if set is non empty then it does have a point of Q^n in its interior. If we have non-countable many such open and disjoint sets then measure goes to infinity. Which means even though the union is a subset of R^n its measure equals to \infty ?

Comment: @canseeker The $\Bbb Q^n$ argument is the way to go. There are only countably many rational points and every non-empty open set of a collection of disjoint open sets has such a point "of its own". Hence there can only be countably non-empty such sets.

Comment: many thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen great argument. I actually had a measure theoretic argument in mind, but yours is way better.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Could you please share it?

Comment: In fact, you gave the argument yourself. Namely that an infinite collection of disjoint nonempty open set would have infinite measure, which contradicts the fact that $[-R,R]^n$ has finite measure. Now if you have a collection of disjoint open sets $(U_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$, write $\Lambda_R:=\{ \lambda \in \Lambda : U_{\lambda} \cap [-R,R]^n \neq \emptyset \}$. By the above reasoning, we get that $\Lambda_R$ is countable. But the set of all the nonempty sets of your collection is $\bigcup_{R\in\mathbb{N}} \Lambda_R$ and therefore countable.